# android:scr attribute not displaying image

Tags: java, android

i want to know when i am using this attribute it does not load the specified image or it does not even work !
        android:scr= "@drawable/bac"
But works fine when i load the image with background attribute .
Below down is the code !! Hope get some help !!

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scr= "@drawable/bac"   // This line does not work 
    android:background="@drawable/bac"
    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things.

One: You use

```
   android:scr= "@drawable/bac"
```

the property is src, like this:

```
   android:src= "@drawable/bac"
```

Two: The problem in this case is because src is a property, but ImageView property. The TextView does not have the src property.

Comment: well thanks my problem solved !!! Really appreciate that Its been couple of weeks first i was typing the name wrong now its clear :P